# Constraining sub-types in a Map attribute declaration

Tags: java, templates, dictionary, generics

Is there any way to declare a Map attribute in such a way that constrains the type of the values mapped to a certain key according to the key's class?

I need a Map that relates WrapperA keys to WrapperB values where both classes are parameterized with a type extending the Contained class.

```
class WrapperA<T extends Contained>
class WrapperB<T extends Contained>
Map<WrapperA, WrapperB> map;
```

However, I want to enforce the entries on the map to be parameterized with the same class. Note that the map can host entries using different types. For instance, `WrapperA<Description>`->`WrapperB<Description>` and `WrapperA<Name>`->`WrapperB<Name>` assuming that Description and Name extend Contained.

In a few words, how can I declare a Map in such a way that behaves like the following class?

```
class Store {

    HashMap<WrapperA<? extends Contained>, WrapperB<? extends Contained>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends Contained> void put(WrapperA<T> w, WrapperB<T> rs) {
        map.put(w, rs);
    }

    public <T extends Contained> WrapperB<T> get(WrapperA<T> w) {
        return (WrapperB<T>) map.get(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem here, didn't you already solve the problem?

Comment: @syntagma the key and value are generic types, he wants different entries to be parameterized on different types so he could insert `WrapperA<Integer>,WrapperB<Integer>` and `WrapperA<String>,WrapperB<String>` for example but he wants to prevent e.g. `WrapperA<String>,WrapperB<Integer>`

Comment: @syntagma The problem is solved using an additional class. However, this means to re-implement the whole interface for the Map methods that I may use within the class using Store. If it's possible to use directly the HashMap or any other map implementation, that would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @niceman Exactly that's the whole point of the question

Comment: You can't, the example that you give (`Store`)  is the idiomatic way to solve this problem. You use encapsulation to ensure the types are the same.

Comment: To supplement @JornVernee, the technique you use in your `Store` class in the question is called *delegation*, it’s an old and respected technique in object-oriented design and programming. Please don’t think there’s anything wrong with it.

Comment: Wikipedia refers to it as [forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_(object-oriented_programming)) and explains the difference between forwarding and delegation.